# toolbar too high in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am using the support v7 Toolbar widget, and generally it works. The toolbar looks great before I call setSupportActionBar(toolbar), just like the second picture. But the height of toolbar has changed after I setSupportActionBar,it became the first picture.

I can't find the right solution in the search engine，and I don't know how to descibe this question in search engine without picture.

Please take a look at the screenshots:

[Innormal Toolbar(First Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oq9fR.png)

[Normal Toolbar(Second Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8qyv.png)

Except for the 2 cases just mentioned, I want to make layout_main looks like this picture, but I don't know how to convert my code from picture1 to this:
[The toolbar that I want to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cCkI.png)

This is my code:

- Styles(v21).xml

  ```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
      <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
      <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
      <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
      <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

      <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
      <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
      <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
  </style>
  ```
- Style.xml

  ```
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
      <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
      <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
      <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
      <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>
  ```
- layout_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:title="Test"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

- MainActivity.java

  ```
  package com.mxdlzg.test;

  import android.graphics.Color;
  import android.os.Build;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;

  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate;

  import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

  import com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation;
  import com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigationItem;

  import java.text.DateFormat;
  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
      private Toolbar toolbar;
      private AHBottomNavigation bottomNavigation;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          //toolbar
          toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
          setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
      }

  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Put this settings in `style.xml`

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

instead of `v21/style.xml`

Thank you.